# Hodge decomposition and Kunneth formula on product manifold

Tags: dg.differential-geometry, riemannian-geometry, soft-question, hodge-theory

Let $M$ be a compact oriented Riemannian manifold. Then we have the famous Hodge decomposition theorem:
$$
\Omega^*(M)= im(d)\oplus \mathcal H^*(M) \oplus im(d^*)
$$
Now, we want to consider the special case $M=M_1\times M_2$ and we can decompose the exterior derivative as $d=d_1+d_2$ and then the adjoint is $d^*=d_1^*+d_2^*$. Of course, we have a Hodge decomposition for $d$.

> But do we have a similar decomposition with regard to a single $d_1$ or $d_2$? Namely, can we find some $\mathcal H_1$ and $\mathcal H_2$ so that
>   $$
> \Omega^*(M_1\times M_2)=im (d_1)\oplus \mathcal H_1 \oplus im(d_1^*) 
> $$
>   $$
> \Omega^*(M_1\times M_2)=im (d_2)\oplus \mathcal H_2 \oplus im(d_2^*) 
> $$

If this was correct, it should be expected that $\mathcal H_1$ is perhaps just the $d_1$-cohomology of $\Omega^*(M)$, namely, $H^*(M_1)\otimes \Omega^*(M_2)$. It seems that further taking $d_2$-cohomology we might arrive at $H^*(M_1\times M_2)$.

Some of my attempts are as follows.

(1) A proof of Hodge decomposition uses the ellipticity of the Laplacian operator $\Delta_d=dd^*+d^*d$. But for a partial Hodge decomposition as above, we should work with $\Delta_{d_1}$ which is only semi-elliptic.

(2) Perhaps the choice of the metric $g$ might be involved. Probably we should use the product metric $g=g_1\times g_2$?